# Unable to delete programatically added contact in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-5.0-lollipop

We have run into a weird problem on our Nexus devices which recently updated to Lollipop.

Contacts that are added through the program can no longer be deleted. It either gives no option to delete or, if it does, then the delete itself doesn't work (even though it says that it does).
Funnily enough, I downloaded a 3rd party contacts application and it has no problem deleting them.

Similarly, we can't delete it through the program.
These are all things that worked perfectly before the upgrade.

This is the code that is used to insert the contact:

```
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
             .build());
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
             .build());

     if(contact.phone != null && contact.phone !=" "){
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contact.phone)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,Phone.TYPE_WORK)
             .build());
     }

     if(contact.phone2 != null && contact.phone2 !=" "){
         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contact.phone2)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                 .build());
     }

     if(contact.phone3 != null && contact.phone3 !=" "){
         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                 .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contact.phone3)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                 .build());
     }

     if(contact.fax != null && contact.fax !=" "){
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contact.fax)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK)
             .build());
     }

     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,(" ".equals(contact.getAddress())?contact.location:contact.getAddress()))
             .build());
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.meuhedet))
             .build());
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, Long.parseLong(Groupid))
             .build());

     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),R.drawable.logo_meuhedet);
     photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, baos.toByteArray())
         .build());

     try {
         ContentProviderResult [] res =ctx.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
         rawContactID = ContentUris.parseId(res[0].uri);
         Log.d(TAG,"contact added = " + rawContactID);
         boolean result = db.saveContactsIntoDatabase(rawContactID, index, ContactKey);

         if(res[0].uri!=null && result){
            ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.successfully_saved_contact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
             }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

As can be see, we save the id returned so that we can then use it in the delete:

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
              .withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactId)})
              .build());
    try {
        ContentProviderResult [] res = ctx.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
         Log.d(TAG,"delete count= " + res[0].count);


         if(res[0].count > 0 && result){
            ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.successfully_deleted_contact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
         }
    }  catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

The delete returns 0 for the number of rows affected so it is obviously not deleting it.

Is this a problem with Lollipop or is something wrong in the way we are adding the contact?

Comment: Weird, I've tested your code (modulo some very minor changes, such as fixing the string comparisons) and it adds and deletes the contact perfectly (Nexus 7, Lollipop). Can you access the contact if you query it with `rawContactId`?

Comment: I tried:   Cursor c1 = ctx.getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
            RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactId)}, null);
   Log.d(TAG,"count = " + c1.getCount()); and get zero lines returned.

Comment: Weird thing is that I downloaded an application called "Contact+" and it has no problems deleting the contact.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct value in rawContactId?

Comment: Yep. I printed them out to be 100% sure. Even if not, that would not explain why I am unable to delete them via the stock contacts program.

Comment: Yes, that is most strange. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce it (both your code and the Contacts app delete it correctly) so I have no idea. Hope you find the cause.

Comment: @matiash Solved it in the end. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of "fighting" with the application I found out the cause.

It appears that you now have to supply a type (StructuredPostal.TYPE) for an address. Without it, it simply doesn't work properly.

This only seems to be the case with Lollipop. We tested it on other versions and no problem.

I would have expected the insert to fail if type is now compulsory.

Comment: Any explanation about how other applications like (Contact+) are able to delete the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that caused some contacts couldn't be deleted. And I found that the problem was because I was using **Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI** instead of global **Contacts.CONTENT_URI**

I don't know why but lot of samples here in StackOverflow use CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI to delete contacts.